# How to use VsCode debug breakpoints for node.js project in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code

I have a node.js project that run in docker, how I can use breakpoints to debug the project?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a normal (non-Docker) development environment, and then use normal tools from there?

Comment: It also seems like there are [a couple of existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D%5Bvisual-studio-code%5D+node+breakpoint+is%3Aquestion) around trying to use VSCode to directly debug a deployed application; do one of those match your symptom better?  What is the actual problem you're running into?